# 1px white spacing in Chrome between div's

Tags: css, google-chrome

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/c6cwbjLz/13/

Basically, I've been trying to make a full-screen 3x2 grid, and have essentially achieved it, however I'm seeing a tiny 1px vertical line between the 2nd and 3rd columns when I hover over the grid items. Where is this coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

I've read elsewhere that including `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` can help when using 3D transformations; however I'm not using any 3D transformations. This line does work to a degree, in that it hides the white line on some sizes, but on others it still appears (I assume when it's not quite divisible by 3?). I've commented this line out in the JSFiddle below so you can easily see the white line which appears on hover.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm seeing, in case it's not happening for you. Though so far I've only encountered this problem in Chrome.

[image]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/c6cwbjLz/13/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    gridSize();
});

jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    gridSize();
});

/* Returns scrollbar width*/
function getScrollBarWidth() {
    var inner = document.createElement('p');
    inner.style.width = "100%";
    inner.style.height = "200px";

    var outer = document.createElement('div');
    outer.style.position = "absolute";
    outer.style.top = "0px";
    outer.style.left = "0px";
    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    outer.style.width = "200px";
    outer.style.height = "150px";
    outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
    outer.appendChild(inner);

    document.body.appendChild(outer);
    var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
    outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
    if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

    document.body.removeChild(outer);

    return (w1 - w2);
};

function gridSize() {
    
    if ($('.box').width() > 0) {
        var w = $(window).width();    
    } else {
        var w = $(window).width() - getScrollBarWidth();
    }

    var h = $(window).height();

    var thirdw, halfw, halfh, overboxw, overboxh;
    
    /* Width needs to be 33%, height needs to be 50% */
    /* Full screen sizes */
    thirdw = w / 3;
    halfh = h / 2;

    $('.box').css({
        "width": thirdw,
            "height": halfh
    });

    /* Set overbox size */

    overboxw = thirdw - 60;
    overboxh = halfh - 60;

    $('.box .overbox').css({
        "width": overboxw,
            "height": overboxh
    });

    /* Resize the images based on the ratio */
    if (thirdw > halfh) {
        jQuery('.box img').css({
            "height": halfh +"px",
   "width": "auto"
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.box img').css({
            //"height": halfh +"px"
        });
    }

    /*
    Bottom's affected:
    .box:hover .title == 110px (needs moving up depending on width of box as content beneath grows in height)
    
    */

}
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.boxWrapper {
    font-size:0;
    /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}

.box {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    z-index:400;
    display:inline-block;
}
.gradient {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    z-index:401;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.box img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    z-index:400;
}
.box .title {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    left:25px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    z-index:404;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box .title:after {
    content:'';
    margin-top:5px;
    display:block;
    height:4px;
    width:60%;
    background:#fff;
}
.box:hover .title {
    bottom:110px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box .overbox {
    background-color: rgba(246, 48, 62, 0.85);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 340px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 403;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
.box:hover .overbox {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box .overbox .tagline {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    font-size:16px;
}

.box:hover .overbox .tagline {
    bottom:20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWrapper">
<div class="box">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <img src="http://www.webtutorialplus.com/Images/css-effects-image/1.jpg" alt="Web Tutorial Plus - Demo" width="300" height="400" />
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
        <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <img src="http://www.webtutorialplus.com/Images/css-effects-image/1.jpg" alt="Web Tutorial Plus - Demo" width="300" height="400" />
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
        <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <img src="http://www.webtutorialplus.com/Images/css-effects-image/1.jpg" alt="Web Tutorial Plus - Demo" width="300" height="400" />
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
        <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <img src="http://www.webtutorialplus.com/Images/css-effects-image/1.jpg" alt="Web Tutorial Plus - Demo" width="300" height="400" />
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
        <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <img src="http://www.webtutorialplus.com/Images/css-effects-image/1.jpg" alt="Web Tutorial Plus - Demo" width="300" height="400" />
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
        <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <img src="http://www.webtutorialplus.com/Images/css-effects-image/1.jpg" alt="Web Tutorial Plus - Demo" width="300" height="400" />
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
        <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
aaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccc
```

Comment: Please include the HTML/CSS to reproduce this problem *in the actual question*. Otherwise, this question risks being closed.

Comment: I've included a JSFiddle link which has the issue inside. Since a bit of JS is used, I assumed that would be easier?

Comment: You should which place code cause your problem rather than put them all on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixel rounding. If your width generated is `1000px`, each column **should** be generated at `333.33̅px`.

However, each browser/version handles decimal pixels differently unfortunately. Here's a handy guide: http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

Shock horror that IE is the worst. If you run it in IE, make sure your window is `1001px` wide and see how **that** renders. I expect that your `333.66̅px`. will unhappily get rounded up to 333.67, and may end up cutting off the 3rd column.

To do what you need to do, you don't actually need JS at all:

http://jsfiddle.net/c6cwbjLz/14/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.boxWrapper {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}
.gradient {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 33.33%;
  z-index: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("http://www.webtutorialplus.com/Images/css-effects-image/1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.box .title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 404;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box .title:after {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 60%;
  background: #fff;
}
.box:hover .title {
  bottom: 110px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box .overbox {
  background-color: rgba(246, 48, 62, 0.85);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*make border and padding include in height/width */
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 403;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.box:hover .overbox {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box .overbox .tagline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.box:hover .overbox .tagline {
  bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWrapper">
  <div class="box gradient">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
      <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box gradient">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
      <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box gradient">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
      <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box gradient">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
      <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box gradient">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
      <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box gradient">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="overbox">
      <div class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur ex velit, eget pellentesque dui dictum at.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccc
```

I have had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480442/width-calc100-3-not-working-properly-in-any-ie) which was fixed with a simple `width: 33.33%`. Note that in my case I needed to use JS to calculate height and widths for something else that couldn't work responsively.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If this is the case then, what would you suggest as a fix? EDIT: Just checked the page rendering in IE:8 and I'm not seeing any white pixel there.

Comment: @Natalie I'm configuring now :).

Comment: That looks great! Thanks; however, I'm still seeing a white line every now and then at certain sizes. For example if .boxwrapper is set  to 1060px wide, and I hover over the first and second grid item quickly, I still see the 1px white gap.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? I'm using `43.0.2357.130 m`. Also what's the behaviour? I'm seeing a white line between boxes 5 and 6, when hovering over either 1, 2 or 3. Just making sure I'm seeing the same things.

Comment: I'm using `43.0.2357.130 m`. And I'm seeing exactly the same thing you currently are :)

Comment: Appears to be a problem with CSS3 Transition on `.overbox`. Add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to `.box .overbox` rule: http://jsfiddle.net/c6cwbjLz/16/

Comment: That seems to have worked brilliantly! Not seeing any white lines now :) Thank you so much for your help, Jamie!